# How to cache data using OkHttp3 in android

Tags: android, okhttp

I am fetching data from node server in listview everytime activity opens it send request to the server and fetch data again.I want to cache data and shows it until some new data is added to the server.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
List<Data> places;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

listView  = findViewById(R.id.listView);
places = new ArrayList<>();

final ProgressDialog prg = new ProgressDialog(Activity2.this);
prg.setMessage("Loading...");
prg.show();

Log.d("OnCreate","Oncreate started");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                          .connectTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                          .readTimeout(22,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                          .writeTimeout(22,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                          .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://tiffino.herokuapp.com/test").build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {

        prg.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

        prg.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for(int i = 0;i < arr.length();i++){

                        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String str1 = obj.getString("Name");

                        Data data = new Data(str1);

                        places.add(data);

                    }

                    PlacesAdapter adapter=  new PlacesAdapter(places,getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

  });

  }
}
```

Someone please let me know what should I do to cache the data.
Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but there are plenty of guides on this. What did you try and why did it fail what you tried?

Comment: I have been through some of them but couldn't understand what exactly is going on as for now I am simply fetching data everytime activity loads.I want some help on that.

Comment: `I have been through some of them but couldn't understand what exactly is going` what do you not understand? Let's try and answer that first.

Comment: Request.Builder().cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE),This it uses Force cache but what if some new data is added on server how would i fetch that.